# ISO date in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, iso

Actully i send date from my front end to mongo then it reduces the date by 1 and when i retrive, it gives correct date but when we put the aggregation on that data according to month and year fetch from $month,$year property, it performs the aggregation according to the less date value why?
if it is ok, then give me solution to perform correct aggregation.
The code for aggregation is -

```
DBObject projectFields = new BasicDBObject();
         projectFields.put("creationDate","$creationDate");
         projectFields.put("month",new BasicDBObject("$month", "$creationDate" ));
         projectFields.put("year",new BasicDBObject("$year", "$creationDate" ));
         projectFields.put("day",new BasicDBObject("$dayOfMonth", "$creationDate" ));
         projectFields.put("batchQty","$batchQty");
         DBObject projectObj = new BasicDBObject("$project", projectFields);
         DBObject groupIdFieldsObj = new BasicDBObject();
         groupIdFieldsObj.put("month","$month");
         groupIdFieldsObj.put("year","$year");
         groupFieldsObj.put("_id", groupIdFieldsObj);
         DBObject groupSumFieldsObj = new BasicDBObject();
         groupSumFieldsObj.put("$sum", "$batchQty");
         groupFieldsObj.put("batchQty", groupSumFieldsObj);
         DBObject groupObj = new BasicDBObject("$group", groupFieldsObj);
         DBObject outCollObj = new BasicDBObject();
         outCollObj.put("$out", "salesExportData");
         coll.aggregate(groupObj,projectObj,outCollObj);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you add some sample document ?

Answer (score 0):

I am just guessing, but I think it's your mongoDB driver in application, it corrects the date when you fetch the data as it reduces when you store it. so balance is alright.

So what's the problem with aggregation is, Aggregation is set(actually array) of operations which runs on Mongo server itself and mongo server doesn't know what smartness your driver has applied and hence it calculates the operation with whatever data is being stored in there and hence the mismatch.

Your driver puts you into problem and helps you till it can help and couldn't help further with aggregation or map-reduce.

I can't get any solution on the top of my head but you can try to adjust the behavior in projection part of aggregation. You need to see on what basis driver is reducing one day? is it based on server timezone? Once you get your answer you can add a balancing act in your aggregation by manipulating the projects.

I understand it looks dirty(read unclean) but then different Mongo drivers are still improving and till then we have to 'adjust'.